# Upgrading Laravel 5.2 to 5.4 and beyond causes infinite recursion in Elouquent GuardsAttributes

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade

I am currently in the process of upgrading a Laravel project that I have "inherited" from some other developers, who are no longer around.

The whole project is built in Laravel 5.2 and has not been updated since, so we have started the process.

When arriving at Laravel 5.4 we are seeing that almost all of our pages that post simply end up in the dreaded "PHP white screen of death" (HTTP error 500), with the following log from PHP:

```
Allowed memory size of xyz bytes exhausted (tried to allocate abc bytes) in php
```

We have tried increasing the memory limit quite a lot (2 GB) and always end up in the same situation.

I then installed Xdebug in our local dev environments, and now I am seeing this error instead:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!


/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php 174
```

Which leads me to believe that something might be amiss in the Database models - and there's a little over 50 models to check.

However I am not very seasoned in Laravel, and neither in upgrading it, so I was hoping that some Laravel guru out there has some quick pointers on what to check to mitigate this error?

Comment: Try to enable errors details in your .env file. Then you will get more information.

Comment: @RainDev I have APP_DEBUG=true in my .env file - are there other settings I can enable to make Laravel more debuggish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the Models that are failing has a Trait attached which overrides `update` and `create` of the model that `use` the trait.

As added in the Laravel migration guide for 5.4 they have made changes to `update` and `create` in traits, so one should use `static::query()->create()` instead of `parent::create()`.

Bug similar to mine here on github with a full explanation:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17876

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest installing this [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar). It adds a bar in the bottom of the screen, so you can see which queries were executed and information about them. I must admit that I haven't used it that much, but I would start there, looking through if there are some kind of rat-king of a query, that exhausts all the resources.

It should be said, that the Debugbar takes additional ressources, monitoring the pages. So I would ensure that you install in on a development-environment, where you can turn the settings all the way up to 10. So you don't just introduce a new bug to your buggy system. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, didn't mention in the post thatt Debugbar is already installed in our local dev environments - and it does indeed log some queries, which will provide a useful trail to follow.